# Scoped Storage - Camera/MediaRecorder not saving recorded video

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder, scoped-storage

For some reason, when using Scoped Storage, MediaRecorder isn't saving the the video to the Scoped Storage location. It works fine in Legacy mode.

Here is my code for my Camera parameters and my initMediaRecorder:

```
public void setCameraParameters() {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Integer> frameRates = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFrameRates();
    if (frameRates != null) {
        Integer max = Collections.max(frameRates);
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(max);
    }
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

    parameters.setExposureCompensation(2);
    if (parameters.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
        parameters.setAutoExposureLock(false);
    }
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}

public void initRecorder() {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);

    if (previewSize != null) {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    }

    if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock();

    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(videoOrientation);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3072 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

    if (!mApp.videoTime) {
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
    } else {
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                //stop video and do stuff
            }


}
```

Here is my code where I name my video file:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q || Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()) {
    Log.d("Video", "Filename is null");
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + FILE_PATH + "/" + mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + filename + FILE_EXT);
    videoFilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +  FILE_PATH + "/" + mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + filename + ".mp4";
} else {
    Log.d("Video", "Storage is not legacy");
    file = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + filename + FILE_EXT);
videoFilename = EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + filename + ".mp4";
}
```

`EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH` is a subfolder inside the scoped directory called by `getExternalFilesDir()`. `videoFilename` is then passed to a File object to create the final video file.

EDIT:

```
FILE_PATH = "/GS2000"
EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = getExternalFilesDir(FILE_PATH).getPath();
```

The CSV files save just fine, but the MP4 files do not.

I checked Logcat, and `videoFilename` isn't null, but for some reason the video file isn't being created. Is there any reason why?

EDIT:

Video filename:

```
videoFile = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + mApp.mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + mApp.sessionDate + " " + mApp.sessionTimeFormatted + MP4_EXT);
```

`mApp` is the Application context.  `mCurPatient` is my `Patient` class, which has multiple fields to store patient data (`patientid` in this case). `sessionDate` is the current date of the recorded session. `sessionTimeFormatted` is the the start time of the recorded session, with colons replaced with underscores. `MP4_EXT` is the string ".mp4".

If session is renamed after completion:

```
if (videoFile != null && videoFile.exists()) {
    Log.d("Video", "Video file does exist");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q || Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()) {
        newVideoFilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + FILE_PATH + "/" + tvPatientID.getText().toString() + "/" + sessionName + ".mp4";
     } else {
          newVideoFilename = EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + tvPatientID.getText().toString() + "/" + sessionName + ".mp4";
     }
}
```

After saving the session, I call this:

```
File videoTo = new File(activity.newVideoFilename);
    if (videoFrom.exists()) {
        videoFrom.renameTo(videoTo);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is how the subfolders are created:

```
private File CreateFile(CharSequence name, CharSequence date) {
    if (checkMediaState(false)) {
        File file1;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q || Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()) {
            Log.d("File", "Creating Legacy File");
            file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + FILE_PATH + "/" + name);
        } else {
            Log.d("File", "Creating Scoped File");
            file1 = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + name);
        }
        Log.d("File", "Creating File 2");
        File file2 = new File(file1, date.toString() + FILE_EXT);
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        file1.mkdirs();
        Log.d("File", "File is not null");
        return file2;
    }
    Log.d("File", "File is null");
    return null;
}
```

`name` is the patient ID.

Comment: You better tell exactly the value of EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH as we have no idea where you are talking about. Also tell the value of file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: I just updated my post.

Comment: Can be but it stays unreadable code. Also i wonder by you post code like `videoFile = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + "/" + mApp.mCurPatient.getPatientid() + "/" + mApp.sessionDate + " " + mApp.sessionTimeFormatted + MP4_EXT);` Unreadable. Just post a simple name. The value. Not all these variables. You want help so dont push us with unreadable things.

Comment: I just added descriptions of each variable

Comment: Wrong. I did not ask for that. I asked for readabke code like newVideoFilename= "patient.mp4". Dont bother us with variables.

Comment: In Logcat, the path prints as `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mobilityresearch.treadmill3/files/GS2000/CS020822101/02.09.2022 08_45_40.mp4`, with the filename being `02.09.2022 08_45_40.mp4`.

Comment: And are subfolders GS2000/CS020822101 created? Where do you create them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241865/discussion-between-pink-jazz-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chatting. Please answer.

Comment: The subfolders GS2000 and CS020822101 are created after creating the first session. GS2000 is the root for session files and CS020822101 is the patient ID. Note that CSV files for the session save just fine but MP4 files do not.

Comment: `file1.mkdirs();` You mean: `if ( !file1.exists()) if ( ! file1.mkdirs()) return null;`

Comment: Nope, did not work.

Comment: If you only would try:  mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "myfile.mp4").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Apparently MediaRecorder isn't recording the file for some reason.